# DOMDocument createComment function doesn't work

Tags: xpath, domdocument

I'm trying to create a comment inside a new `<div>` using XPath and DOMDocument.
Here's the process that I'm using:

I'm looking for a script tag using XPath in my DOM, then I loop the results and trying to create a new element using DOMDocument and insert it:

```
$xpath   = new DOMXPath( $dom );
$scripts = $xpath->query( '//script[@src[contains(., "//cdn.chitika.net/getads.js" )]]' );

foreach ( $scripts as $script ) {
    $external_tag = $dom->createElement( 'div' );
    $external_tag->setAttribute( 'data-lazy-widget', null );
    $external_tag->appendChild( $dom->createComment( 'Hello World' ) );
    $script->parentNode->insertBefore( $external_tag, $script );
}
```

It sets the attribute and inserts it before the $script node well, but in the DOM just shows an empty `<div>`.

```
<div data-lazy-widget> </div>
```

So, I think `$dom->createComment( 'Hello World' )` doesn't work, or maybe I'm doing something wrong?

What can I do?

Comment: Your code works - https://eval.in/771420

Comment: Weird, doesn't work in my app, so maybe is another code interfering with this code? Thanks.